# На всё отвечает NO | C++

Tags: c++, строки, find

На всё отвечает NO, а должна найти слово "nozm" или "NOZM" и сказать YES - если есть или NO - если нет

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
void himoji(char* ar){
int o=strlen(ar);
int k=0;
for(int i=0; i<o; i++){
  if((ar[i]=='N' || ar[i]=='n')&&(ar[i+1]=='O' || ar[i+1]=='o')&&(ar[i+2]=='Z' || ar[i+2]=='z')&&(ar[i+3]=='M' || ar[i+3]=='m')){
  k=1;
  }
  else {
   k=0;
  }
}
if (k==1 && k<4){
  cout<<"YES";
}
else {
  cout<<"NO";
}
}
int main() {
char *ar = new char[1000];
cin>>ar;
himoji(ar);
}
```

пример: aaanozmaaaa - YES 
aaaNOZMaa -YES  
aaaNOMZaaa -NO
aaanokmaaa - NO

Comment: Как только вы находите свое NOZM, а потом **опять не находите* - вы затираете значение k.

Comment: `k==1&& k<4` эквивалентно `k==1`, вероятно подразумевалось ИЛИ? Но тогда лишнее первое)

Comment: "На всё отвечает.... " ?... Программа не отвечает, а выполняет то, что вы пишете. Правильно сказать типа " Всегда получаю результат..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ладно, будем считать, что ни `toupper`, ни `strstr` недоступны...

Первое -

```
for(int i=0; i< o - 3; i++)   // -3 - чтоб не вылазить за пределы строки!!!
```

Второе -

```
    .... (ar[i+3]=='M' || ar[i+3]=='m'))
    {
        k = 1;
        break;
    }
```

После чего просто

```
if (k)
{
    cout<<"YES";
}
else
{
    cout<<"NO";
}
```